# extjs combo Box with hasone association property + editable grid

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, associations

I have a IPIdentifierMod model that has a hasone association with BaseInfo model

```
Ext.define('JP.model.IPIdentifierMod', {
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
fields:[
    'enterpriseIdType',
    {
        name: 'referenceVerifiedDate',
        type: 'date',
        convert: function(v, record) {
            return Ext.Date.format((new Date(v)), 'Y-m-d');
            console.log(v);
            console.log(record);
        }
    }
],associations: [
    { type: 'hasOne',
        model: 'BaseInfoMod',
        name:'enterpriseIdType'
    }
]
```

});

baseInfo:

```
Ext.define('JP.model.BaseInfoMod', {
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
fields:[
    'typeId',
    'typeName',
    'parentId',
    'priority'
],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root:'results',
        idProperty: 'typeId'
    },
    api: {
        read : contextPath + '/baseInfo/getBaseInfo'
    },
    extraParams: {
        baseEntityNo: ''
    }
}
```

});

and I show IPIdentifierMod data in a grid

corresponding grid column to show naemType of BaseInfo is:

```
    {
    header:'Name Type',
    dataIndex:'enterpriseIdType',
    sortable:true,
    renderer: function(value) {
        return value.typeName;
    }
},
```

This works fine. The enterpriseIdType.typeName is displayed in the column.

I now added a RowEditingPlugin and added the following editor to this column

```
        editor: {
        allowBlank: false,
        xtype: 'combobox',
        displayField: 'typeName',
        valueField: 'typeId',
        store: 'EnterpriseIdType',
    }
```

In the editor,the value of the field is "[object Object]" . 
I need to render this object to display the name just like I did to the actual column.
Also when I choose an item in the ComboBox, an enterpriseIdType object is not created in the data, 
it just saves the value of the field specified in the valueField.
I searched it and find something like my problem without any answer.
[sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?245015-using-ComboBox-on-HasOne-association-field)

thank you

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  How?